# Getting an specific <p> inside a div whit only class, no ID

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, parent-child

Ok here is the part of my code >>

```
<div class="storeMenuTwoItem" onclick="addToCart()">
  <img src="resources/img/si/SI_EmpireDesodorante.jpg" class="storeMenuBodyTwoImg" />
  <p class="storeMenuTwoBodyText">Empire Desodo.</p>
  <p class="storeMenuTwoBodyPrice">23 R$</p>
</div>
<div class="storeMenuTwoItem" onclick="addToCart()">
  <img src="resources/img/si/SI_EspumaBarbear.jpg" class="storeMenuBodyTwoImg" />
  <p class="storeMenuTwoBodyText">Espuma Barbear</p>
  <p class="storeMenuTwoBodyPrice">22 R$</p>
</div>
<div class="storeMenuTwoItem" onclick="addToCart()">
  <img src="resources/img/si/SI_ShampooAntCaspa.jpg" class="storeMenuBodyTwoImg" />
  <p class="storeMenuTwoBodyText">Shampoo AC</p>
  <p class="storeMenuTwoBodyPrice">33 R$</p>
</div>
```

I want to use javascript to get the actual div that is being clicked, this onclick event shold add to cart the div.p(class="storeMenuTwoBodyText").textContent (something like that i mean) and put on the cart that is done already.

Its my first question here, sorry if i have to be more specific you guys can comment down bellow and i edit the post, i will place the javascript code i have already here >>

```
function addToCart() {
    storeTwoItemInfo.style.display = "block";
    storeTwoItemHeader.textContent = this.textContent;
}
```

Ah yes i have the var's and everything setted already.

Answer (score 1):

When invoked by a click, a function's context includes a variable called `event`, which contains information about the click event that invoked it. In particular, `event.target` will give you the element that was clicked on.

```js
function addToCart() {
  console.log(event.target);
}
```

```html
<div class="storeMenuTwoItem" onclick="addToCart()">
  <img src="resources/img/si/SI_EmpireDesodorante.jpg" class="storeMenuBodyTwoImg" />
  <p class="storeMenuTwoBodyText">Empire Desodo.</p>
  <p class="storeMenuTwoBodyPrice">23 R$</p>
</div>
<div class="storeMenuTwoItem" onclick="addToCart()">
  <img src="resources/img/si/SI_EspumaBarbear.jpg" class="storeMenuBodyTwoImg" />
  <p class="storeMenuTwoBodyText">Espuma Barbear</p>
  <p class="storeMenuTwoBodyPrice">22 R$</p>
</div>
<div class="storeMenuTwoItem" onclick="addToCart()">
  <img src="resources/img/si/SI_ShampooAntCaspa.jpg" class="storeMenuBodyTwoImg" />
  <p class="storeMenuTwoBodyText">Shampoo AC</p>
  <p class="storeMenuTwoBodyPrice">33 R$</p>
</div>
```

Comment: In this case it will give me the entire <div> info ? like the IMG, P attributes and etc?

Comment: 'Scripts.js:664 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'textContent' of undefined
    at addToCart (Scripts.js:664)
    at HTMLDivElement.onclick (VM26 Store.aspx:293)' this is the error i got now

Comment: @MatheusSoaresKirchesch it gives you the most specific element clicked on, so if the user clicks on the `img` or the text in a `p` tag, that element will be returned. In this case you can use `event.target.parentElement` to get the parent `div`. However, if the user clicks some empty space that's within the div but is not within any of the child elements, the `div` will be returned by `event.target`. You could check the class or some other attribute of `event.target` to determine which case you're in.

Comment: Welcome to SO, by the way! Your question is a little vague, so I'm a bit unable to provide a complete solution, but hopefully this answer can give you a push in the right direction. Per your second comment, feel free to ask another question, as I have no way of knowing how you changed your function.

Comment: I will do my compromisse rn, i will be back latter today, if you are free to help me latter, i will recoment here, anyway thanks for the knowledge

Comment: Hey bro, idk if you are free RN, but i did it like itemHeaderText.textContent = this.querySelector('.storeMenuTwoBodyText').textContent; and i got the following error > Scripts.js:661 Uncaught TypeError: this.querySelector is not a function
    at addToCart (Scripts.js:661)
    at HTMLDivElement.onclick (Store.aspx:212)

Comment: Hi again, I think you were trying to respond to someone else. `this` will be the `window` at this point, which is not helpful. Please reread my answer telling you that the click target is available as `event.target`. And again, I have no idea what you changed or how your function reads right now so I would suggest starting a new question.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the clicked `div` element as `this` in HTML attribute:

```
<div class="storeMenuTwoItem" onclick="addToCart(this)">
```

Than you can get `p` with a specific class from it with the `querySelector` function:

```
function addToCart(element) {
    storeTwoItemInfo.style.display = "block";
    storeTwoItemHeader.textContent = element.querySelector('.storeMenuTwoBodyText').textContent;
}
```

Comment: Oh, i will try it out latter, thanks for the answer, when i get back home i will get it working, im new to codding, its allways nice to discover new functions

Comment: Oh, I hurried a bit and mistaken. Now it should works.

Answer (score 0):

querySelector is your friend

```
 var div = document.querySelector('div.storeMenuTwoItem');
 var p= div.querySelector('p.storeMenuTwoBodyText');
```

Comment: Thanks bro i will try it out, you had the same idea Nina, nice idea btw

Answer (score 0):

Get click element from `event.target` property. It can be div itself or any element inside it. Check which element it is by class name and if it is not div element then get div-element by `parentElement` property. Then from this div element you can access any element of it by class name.

```
function addToCart() {
  console.log(event.target.className);
  var divElement = event.target;

  if(event.target.className !== 'storeMenuTwoItem'){
     divElement = event.target.parentElement;
  }
  console.log(divElement.className);

  var pElement =divElement.getElementsByClassName('storeMenuTwoBodyText').length > 0 ?                    divElement.getElementsByClassName('storeMenuTwoBodyText')[0] : null ;

  if(pElement){
     console.log(pElement.textContent);
     //alert(pElement.textContent);
     storeTwoItemInfo.style.display = "block";
     storeTwoItemHeader.textContent = pElement.textContent;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Guys i found a way to do it, i took all your ideas and mixed some stuff >> 
`function addToCart() {
    storeTwoItemInfo.style.display = "block";

```
storeTwoModalPhoto.src = event.target.querySelector(".storeMenuBodyTwoImg").src;
storeTwoModalHeader.innerHTML = event.target.querySelector(".storeMenuTwoBodyText").innerHTML;
storeTwoModalPrice.innerHTML = event.target.querySelector(".storeMenuTwoBodyPrice").innerHTML;
storeTwoModalText.innerHTML = event.target.querySelector(".storeMenuBodyTwoImg").alt;
```

}`

Thanks for the help, take care.